# Как сделать так что бы ререндерился 1 элемент FlatList React Native

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/ryD4VtV9H
если кликнуть по элементу листа то в консоль пишеться 6 раз лог, это как пример, у меня на самом деле очень большой лист и когда он ререндерится то все подвисает, как сделать так что бы ререндерился только элемент по которому клик ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**: В вашем случае проблему решает использование собственной функции проверки изменения props в **React.memo**, передается вторым аргументом:

```
const Item = React.memo(
  ({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) => {
    console.log('rerender - ', title);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => onSelect(id)}
        style={[
          styles.item,
          { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
        ]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.selected === nextProps.selected);
```

Исправленый пример тут: https://snack.expo.io/Hyr6D6H9S

Про проблему можно почитать тут(англ): https://itnext.io/phantom-props-unnecessary-renders-and-what-no-one-told-me-about-memo-b34ebbd48c65

---

Если бекенд поддерживает, оптимизируйте ваш FlatList добавив пагинацию(Pagination) используя события `onEndReached` и `onEndReachedThreshold` для работы со скроллом.

Пример можно глянуть тут(англ.): https://blog.apollographql.com/loading-data-into-react-natives-flatlist-9646fa9a199b

Comment: не подходит, у меня просто єто календарь и вывожу ячейки дня, и на екране как миним 2.5 месяца помещаеться тоесть примерно 75 дней по которым можно кликать

Comment: у меня при использовании React.memo, и в вашем примере  - лист глючит, рандомно выбираются объекты листа непонятным образом

Comment: Во-первых ошибка в том что одинаковые id у 3,4,5 айтема.Во вторых, если поставить консоль лог в onSelect, хорошо видно, что из-за неправильно использованного замыкания, selected для каждого Item свой, поэтому лист ведет себя неадекватно.

Answer (score 0):

если привратить Item в класс то работает:

```
class ItemClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleOnSelect = this.handleOnSelect.bind(this);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (
      this.props.id !== nextProps.id
      || this.props.title !== nextProps.title
      || this.props.selected !== nextProps.selected
    ) {
      console.log('shouldComponentUpdate true:  ', nextProps.title, nextProps.selected);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  handleOnSelect() {
     const { id, onSelect } = this.props;
     onSelect(id);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('rerender')
    const { title, selected } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.handleOnSelect}
        style={[
          styles.item,
          { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
        ]}
      >
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```